# Rails - Linking to static files inside of controller views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have some static JS files I would like to include in a rails controller view, unfortunately simply placing them in the appropriate view folder gets me a 404 response. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to javascript inside your view file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  //code goes here
</script>
```

OR

If you want to load JS file then need to place them in app/assets/javascripts directory.

if you have a file your-js-file.js then place it under app/assets/javascripts directory

and add the below line in your application.js

```
//= require your-js-file
```

It will be loaded automatically by Rails

Comment: you mean <= require your-js-file > for the second part? How do I reference it in the HTML code?

Comment: No. This line must be placed in application.js file

Comment: Gotcha, but how do I reference the script within the html code? Just use the `<script>` tag? What do I put under `src`?